# Hover Menu Issue on Ipad back and forth

Tags: css, ipad, twitter-bootstrap, menu, hover

I've been pulling my hair out trying to get my CSS hover menu to work properly on iPad. I have tried applying hover classes using javascript with the same result, so it must be in the css. The site also utilizes twitter bootstrap.

What happens currently is that on a tap, the dropdown/link hover state show for a split second, then the previous link dropdown/hover show, then it shows the correct one again and it remains open as it should.

EDIT: In case anyone else has this problem, update bootstrap (primarily the dropdown class) and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated bootstrap, primarily the dropdown class javascript.